# Refs are not available on initial page load

Tags: reactjs

I need to create thousands of elements and then perform some work based on their refs.

The problem however is that the refs are all undefined on the initial render. I need them to be available on initial page load.

[You can find my codesandbox here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-b17h2g?file=/src/App.tsx) Once you click the button (which forces a rerender), all refs are defined as expected.

Here is the source code for completeness:

```
import { useRef, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const refs = useRef(new Map());

  const [bla, setBla] = useState(0);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setBla((prevState) => prevState + 1)}>
        click me ({bla})
      </button>

      <div style={{ display: "grid", gridTemplateColumns: "1fr 1fr" }}>
        <div>
          {[...Array(100)].map((_, k) => (
            <div key={k} ref={(ref) => refs.current.set(k, ref)}>
              {k}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
        <div>
          {[...Array(100)].map((_, k) => (
            <div key={k}>{refs.current.get(k) ? "defined" : "undefined"}</div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: You can't ref elements until they've been rendered. Sounds like refs [may not be the best choice for whatever you're trying to achieve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/399876). The point of refs is to provide an escape hatch out of React to manipulate DOM elements after a render, not to be used unless  there's no other good choice. From the stub code you've shown, normal state seems best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with `useEffect`. ([codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-xsfrp9?file=/src/App.tsx))

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const refs = useRef(new Map());

  const outerRef = useRef(null);
  const [outerRefLoaded, setOuterRefLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // setTimeout(() => {
    setOuterRefLoaded(outerRef.current !== null);
    // }, 5000);
  }, [outerRef]);

  const [bla, setBla] = useState(0);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setBla((prevState) => prevState + 1)}>
        click me ({bla})
      </button>

      <div style={{ display: "grid", gridTemplateColumns: "1fr 1fr" }}>
        <div ref={outerRef}>
          {[...Array(100)].map((_, k) => (
            <div key={k} ref={(ref) => refs.current.set(k, ref)}>
              {k}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
        <div>
          {!outerRefLoaded && "loading..."}
          {outerRefLoaded &&
            [...Array(100)].map((_, k) => (
              <div key={k}>{refs.current.get(k) ? "defined" : "undefined"}</div>
            ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```