# React ref: How to prevent component from being undefined on page load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-ref

Consider the following;

I have two primereact components a Input and a Dropdown.

```
const stateInputRef: React.MutableRefObject<Dropdown> = useRef<Dropdown>(null);
const zipInputRef: React.MutableRefObject<InputMask> = useRef<InputMask>(null);
```

I've run into a problem where each components `onChange` and `value` props are being used so I have to use a `refs` to get the value for each.

This works fine **after** the page load but as you might know it's `undefined` on page load.

This other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75128757/refs-are-not-available-on-initial-page-load) seems to have a solution to the problem, but I' couldn't get it to work:

I did something like this:

```
  const stateInputRef: React.MutableRefObject<Dropdown> = useRef<Dropdown>(null);
  const zipInputRef: React.MutableRefObject<InputMask> = useRef<InputMask>(null);

  const [isHandleZipReady, setIsHandleZipReady] = useState<boolean>(false);
const [isHandleStateReady, setIsHandleStateReady] = useState<boolean>(false);

useEffect(() => {
    setIsHandleZipReady(zipInputRef.current !== null);
    setIsHandleStateReady(stateInputRef.current !== null);
}, [zipInputRef, stateInputRef]);

{
  isStateDropdownReady && <Dropdown ref={stateInputRef} />;
}

{
  isZipInputReady && <InputMask ref={zipInputRef} />;
}
```

But the components properties on the `.current` object still `undefined`

Anyone ever solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You appear to have a circular dependency here; the Dropdown and InputMask components which populate the refs only get rendered once the refs are populated. You should check for `ref.current` before actually operating on the ref, not before rendering the component that the ref will hold.

Comment: @ChrisHeald Thanks for responding! Could you please expand on what you mean with an example?

Comment: Reading [the documentation](https://react.dev/learn/referencing-values-with-refs#refs-and-the-dom) would be more instructive. Assigning `ref={ref}` causes React to store a reference to a DOM node in the ref. However, you are waiting until the ref exists to render the component which will cause the ref to be stored. This is a catch-22.